# Need to close a jframe while showing another one

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am building a desktop student management app in java. So I need to close the current JFRAME while  an another JFRAME  is visible(after closing the new jframe old jframe  should be visible ). Could  you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic idea is generally not recommended. You can have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) for the long winded discussion.

Generally it's recommended to use a `CardLayout` for these type of operations, see [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

What you want to try and do is decouple of the navigation decision making from the views themselves - there's no reason why the first and second view should ever care about each other OR be backing decisions about how the user should navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JFrame#dispose to close just one frame, this ofcourse requires a reference to the JFrame you want to dispose

Comment: But I need to show the old JFrame as soon as I close the new Jframe.

Comment: Do they need to be two seperate Windows? If not take a look at CardLayout  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: Yes the should  be in separate windows .

Comment: Play arround with dispose on both Frames, to make one visible again you have to call pack or show according to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037132/java-swing-dispose-a-jframe-does-not-clear-its-controls

Comment: Thanks RSDinh for your support  but it didn't solve my problem :(